# Finding correlation between an event and data in R

Tags: r, triggers, correlation, cross-correlation

I'm trying to find out how certain events affect visitors to a webpage. For example, I have a table which contains the amount of new organic visitor per minute and datetimes for TV advertisements from the last two months. For example:

df:

```
+------------------+----------+----------+
|     datetime     |  adshown | visitors |
+------------------+----------+----------+
| 2017-06-07 13:00 | 1        |        1 |
| 2017-06-07 13:01 | NA       |        3 |
| 2017-06-07 13:02 | 1        |        9 |
| 2017-06-07 13:03 | NA       |        4 |
| 2017-06-07 13:04 | NA       |       11 |
| 2017-06-07 13:05 | NA       |        7 |
+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Since the effect from showing an ad will not instantly convert to a visitor but rather rise the amount of visitors for a few minute window, I tried to see the correlation with the cross correlation function which is able to take in to account lag

```
ccf(df$visitors, df$adshown)
```

However, using this seemed to give me a graph for completely uncorrelated data:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w3wM.png

Could this be the result of using the wrong method or are our ads and visitors simply uncorrelated? 
Here's dput data for the first 20 rows:

```
structure(list(datetime2 = structure(c(1491166800, 1491166860, 
 1491166920, 1491166980, 1491167040, 1491167100, 1491167160, 1491167220, 
 1491167280, 1491167340, 1491167400, 1491167460, 1491167520, 1491167580, 
 1491167640, 1491167820, 1491167880, 1491168060, 1491168120, 1491168180
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), visits = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0), STATION = c("0", 
"WEB MISC", "0", "0", "0", "0", "YOUTOO AM", "ES TV", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "ES CARS"), ad2 = c(0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2)), .Names = 
c("datetime2", 
 "visits", "STATION", "ad2"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried to plot the data to see and assess any correlations?

Comment: Any tips on how I would plot it? Just putting them on the same graph would be quite confusing since the data is from a two months and the data for ads is basically just 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of your data, e.g. using `dput()`

Comment: If your NA values mean "no ad shown", try changing them to zero.

Comment: [Here's the first 20 rows of my data](https://pastebin.com/xMeb87yh). Thanks for helping me out, @Jimbou

Comment: Please paste the `dput` output in your question by editing rather providing a link.

Comment: For the ccf function I changed the NA's to zeros. Good note! @BenBolker

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the note, I'm new to stackoverflow so it's good to learn how to format questions right. @Jimbou